# Rails FormHelper each radio and label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formhelper

I'm working with rails 5.1.2 and ruby 2.2.6. I'm trying to write an `each` loop on a collection and generate a rabio button and a corresponding label for it in my `erb` view. So far, I came to this unsatisfying result:

```
<% @idea.discussions.each do |discussion| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag :discussion, discussion.id %>
  <%= label_tag "discussion_" + discussion.id.to_s, discussion.title %>
<% end %>
```

This generates the following HTML for one element of the collection:

```
<input name="discussion" id="discussion_3" value="3" type="radio">
<label for="discussion_3">Main discussion</label>
```

What is unsatisfying for me is the first argment of the `label_tag`, as I build manually the value of the `for` attribute of the `label` tag. What is the rails way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can try that:

```
<% @idea.discussions.each do |discussion| %>
  <label for="discussion-<%= discussion.id%>">
    <span><%= discussion.title %></span>
    <%= radio_button_tag "discussions[discussion_id]", discussion.id, false, { id: "discussion-#{discussion.id}"} %>
  </label>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is this `label_for` tag? Can't find it in the rails API. Furthermore, my ruby interpreter seems not like the `#` character in the `radio_button_tag`. What could I have missed?

Comment: @Rémi Doolaeghe
I've fix mistype in code example `label for=....` It wraps your radiobutton.
Do you have `#` symbol in double-quotes? # in double-quoutes uses by  Ruby string interpolation method.

Comment: That's a working solution, so I'll accept it. Though, I have an additionnal need. As my goal is generating tabs, I need the label and the radio to be siblings and not parent-child. As I need to style my label depending on the status (`checked`) of the radio and CSS3 doesn't have parent selector, I'm stuck...